# npm run dev ERR - cannot find module and cannot solve with 'npm install'

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, npm-install

I have created a next.js app, but when I try to `npm run dev`, it shows this error to me.

[npm run dev error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YW67.png)

What should I do?

- Node.js version: 12.0.0
- npm version: 7.10.2

I also have tried `npm install` and then `npm run dev` but it still got the same problem.

My script from package.json

```json
{
  "name": "with-mongodb",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mongodb": "^3.5.9",
    "next": "latest",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

---

**Edit:** I created the project by running the following command:

```
npx create-next-app --example with-mongodb mflix
```

Comment: to me, this works fine. Make sure you are in the right folder/project. I ran the above command and then -> cd mflix -> npm install and then npm run dev

everything works fine

Comment: May I ask if it has anything to do with node.js or npm

Comment: I don't think so. try to run this command. 

npx create-next-app --example with-mongodb newmflix && cd newmflix && npm install && npm run dev

don't change anything and let me know

Comment: After I run all of that. It works. But it ask me to input the mongodb URI which I do in ".env.local" . Also with the sample database. But after I ctrl+c out it ask that you want to terminate batch job or not which I answer no. After that I try to run again and it give me an error again.

Comment: My error - 
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Faijiuy\Desktop\University Classes_Materials\Senior Project 1\Test Next-js\newmflix\node_modules\next\dist\bin\next'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Comment: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! with-mongodb@0.1.0 dev: `next dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the with-mongodb@0.1.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Comment: ok I would be happy to help you. But I don’t find comments as right place to discuss.

Comment: I tried to move this thread to chat. But you don’t have enough reputation points. So stackoverflow does not allow that action. We need to find another way for communication for temporarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the cause of this issue. I believe you are using windows

I am expecting every time you quit or exit the dev environment. Terminal asks you to confirm `Terminate batch job (Y/N)`. In case you press Y PowerShell removes some files from next's package. And then next time you are not able to run the dev environment.

Everything will work fine if you press N and you do not `Terminate batch job`.

unfortunately, I don't know how PowerShell works on Windows and why it's asking you to `Terminate batch job`.